# Why does it take more time when you run a LINQ OrderBy before Select?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, ienumerable, deferred-execution

While writing a solution for a coding problem I discovered an interesting behavior of my LINQ statements. I had two scenarios:

First:

```
arr.Select(x => x + 5).OrderBy(x => x)
```

Second:

```
arr.OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => x + 5)
```

After a little bit of testing with System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch I got the following results for an integer array of length 100_000.

For the first approach:

```
00:00:00.0000152
```

For the second:

```
00:00:00.0073650
```

Now I'm interested in why it takes more time if I do the ordering first. I wasn't able to find something on google so I thought about it by myself.

I ended up with 2 Ideas:
1. The second scenario has to convert to IOrderedEnumerable and then back to IEnumerable while the first scenario only has to convert to IOrderedEnumerable and not back.
2. You end up having 2 loops. The first for sorting and the second for the selecting while approach 1 does everything in 1 loop.

So my question is why does it take much more time to do the ordering before select?

Comment: Is this linq2entities or linq2objects or what? The optimizations and the performance highly depend on the underlying provider.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. I just run the query on a normal integer array. I don't have any access to a database or something like that.

Comment: By the way both of your assumptions are whrong. 1:, an `IOrederEnumerable` **is** an `IEnumerable` and thus conversion does not cost anything. 2: the query does not determine how many loops are actually **executed**.

Comment: ok that's right haven't thought about that

Comment: Just a sidenote that when you benchmark two sets of code you should try working with larger data sets because the margin of error is very small and there could be other factors in play. Try making them last at least a few seconds.

Comment: Proper benchmarking is not easy thing. You should trust your measurements. Use this https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html

Comment: note: `arr.Select(x => x + 5).OrderBy(x => x)` by itself **doesn't actually do anything** (except build the map of what to do later) - nor does `arr.OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => x + 5)`. LINQ in this case is *deferred execution* - unless you show how / if you're actually enumerating that...

Comment: Try a larger data set and enumerate as @MarcGravell said. Basically change it to ```var output = arr.Select(x => x + 5).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();```

Comment: @MarcGravell You're right for the benchmarking I had a .ToArray() at the end of the query

Comment: @niklasstoffers well, if you *actually care about the perf here*, you probably wouldn't use LINQ *anyway*: `var x = new int[arr.Length]; for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length; i++) x[i] = arr[i] + 5; Array.Sort(x);` - I would expect that to be noticeably faster. Perhaps also thinking about `ArrayPool<T>` etc if it is a temp array.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm actually not 100% sure about that. As far as I know the performance of OrderBy is better when dealing with large arrays.

Comment: @niklasstoffers compared to an in-place sort? as they say: [citation needed] - and don't forget the sheer lambda overhead is very significant here

Comment: @niklasstoffers using a modified version of Dmitry's test rig: OrderBySelect: 223, 226, 227, 228, 228, 230 average : 227
SelectOrderBy: 217, 219, 219, 220, 222, 223 average : 220
InPlaceSort: 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57 average : 57 - so, about 4 times faster

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok you're right. Haven't thought of the in-place thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which Linq-provider you have, there may happen some optimization on the query. E.g. if you´d use some kind of database, chances are high your provider would create the exact same query for both statements similar to this one:

```
select myColumn from myTable order by myColumn;
```

Thus performamce should be identical, no matter if you order first in Linq or select first.

As this does not seem to happen here, you probably use Linq2Objects, which has no optimization at all. So the order of your statements may have an efffect, in particular if you´d have some kind of filter using `Where` which would filter many objects out so that later statements won´t operate on the entire collection.

To keep long things short: the difference most probably comes from some internal initialzation-logic. As a dataset of 100000 numbers is not really big - at least not big enough - even some fast initialization has a big impact.

Comment: Check the comments on the question. There's no SQL involved.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti I know, that´s why I wrote the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: For the benchmarking test I removed the where statements. Both queries where actually the same with the only difference of the order of .OrderBy() and .Select(). So maybe it's the internal initialization logic you spoke about

Answer (score 3):

Let's have  a look at the sequences:

```
private static void UnderTestOrderBySelect(int[] arr) {
  var query = arr.OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => x + 5); 

  foreach (var item in query)
    ;
}

private static void UnderTestSelectOrderBy(int[] arr) {
  var query = arr.Select(x => x + 5).OrderBy(x => x);  

  foreach (var item in query)
    ;
}

// See Marc Gravell's comment; let's compare Linq and inplace Array.Sort
private static void UnderTestInPlaceSort(int[] arr) {
  var tmp = arr;
  var x = new int[tmp.Length];

  for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
    x[i] = tmp[i] + 5;

  Array.Sort(x);
}
```

In order to perform benchmark, let's run `10` times and average `6` middle results:

```
private static string Benchmark(Action<int[]> methodUnderTest) {
  List<long> results = new List<long>();

  int n = 10;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    Random random = new Random(1);

    int[] arr = Enumerable
      .Range(0, 10000000)
      .Select(x => random.Next(1000000000))
      .ToArray();

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();

    methodUnderTest(arr);

    sw.Stop();

    results.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  }

  var valid = results
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .Skip(2)                  // get rid of top 2 runs
    .Take(results.Count - 4)  // get rid of bottom 2 runs
    .ToArray();

  return $"{string.Join(", ", valid)} average : {(long) (valid.Average() + 0.5)}";
}
```

Time to run and have a look at the results:

```
  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    $"OrderBy + Select: {Benchmark(UnderTestOrderBySelect)}",
    $"Select + OrderBy: {Benchmark(UnderSelectOrderBy)}",
    $"Inplace Sort:     {Benchmark(UnderTestInPlaceSort)}");

  Console.WriteLine(report);
```

**Outcome:** (Core i7 3.8GHz, .Net 4.8 IA64)

```
OrderBy + Select: 4869, 4870, 4872, 4874, 4878, 4895 average : 4876
Select + OrderBy: 4763, 4763, 4793, 4802, 4827, 4849 average : 4800
Inplace Sort:     888, 889, 890, 893, 896, 904 average : 893
```

I don't see any *significant difference*, `Select + OrderBy` seems to be slightly more efficient (about 2% gain) than `OrderBy + Select`. Inplace Sort, however, has *far better* performance (`5` *times*)  than any of Linq.

Comment: Should the array initialization be during the test time?

Comment: @Amy B: Nice catch! Thank you! I've changed the experiment

Comment: can I propose an addition for context: `private static void InPlaceSort()
    {
        var tmp = arr;
        var x = new int[tmp.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
            x[i] = tmp[i] + 5;
        Array.Sort(x);
    }` - i.e. no LINQ

Comment: @Marc Gravell: As we can expect inplace sort (`Array.Sort`) has far better performance (`5` times faster)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thanks - that matches my results; I'm always slightly depressed when people insist on using LINQ on everything : fine for readability, but it isn't a performance API